# searching for the maximum in text file

Tags: c

everyone! I'm a beginner in programming, and I'm particularly interested in language C. I'm sorry if the things I'm asking are too obvious, but, as I've already mentioned, I'm just a novice. Also, this is my first post, and I'm sorry that I don't know how to use editing mode

So, suppose I have a structure students, which consists of their names, gpa and number of completed assignments:

```
typedef struct {

   char name[20];
    
   int gpa;
    
   int assignments

} students;
```

And the content of my file is:

```
Name          GPA        Assignments
Antonio        3              5
Christine      2              2
Veronika       3              7
Jade           1              3
```

I want to implement the function bestStudent which has to return a pointer to the best student, if this student has the highest gpa; however, if there are several students who have the same highest gpa, then the best student is the student who has the highest gpa and the highest number of assignments. But if there are several best students with both highest gpa and highest number of assignments, then the function should return a null pointer.

Actually, I searched in Internet how to find the maximum value in the array, so I know how to implement it if I should only look at the gpa. But how can I also look at the number of the assignments, if there are for example, two students with the same highest gpa? I should return the pointer to that student.
Suppose, that n is a number of students and there could be at most 10 students.

```
    students* bestStudent (int n, students Student[10]){
      int l=0;
      int maximum = Student[l].gpa;
      for (int s=0; s<n; s++){
        if (Student[s].gpa > maximum){
          l=s;
          maximum = Student[s].gpa;
          return &Student[l];
        }
      }
      return NULL;
   }
```

I don't understand how to check the number of assignments if there are two or more students with the same gpa. Do I need to create one more loop to check this? I am really sorry for such questions if they seem stupid for you :)

Comment: You have not completed the array parse when you `return &Student[l];` and anyway `l` is always `0`. When you find a new maximum, set `l = s` and wait until the end of the loop to return. If there is at least one element, the return value cannot `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is essentially that you are returning too early. There could be multiple values greater than the current maximum. Let me give you an example.

Let's say the gpas were 1.7, 2.7, 2.0, 3.9, 4.0.
Your code will see that 2.7 is bigger than 1.7, and then return that value since it's greater. That's obviously not correct, since we want 4.0 to be the maximum. Basically you want to return only after you've done all the necessary comparisons. Also, you want to have a check to make sure that the student has the highest gpa **and** the largest number of assignments.

Also, with regards to two students with the same gpa, that should be taken care of with the explanation above. There isn't necessarily anything special you need for that. The student with the higher number of assignments will be returned.

Comment: Oh, I got it.. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, I would appreciate it if you could upvote or accept my answer, or both. :)